# MSSQL Server for Linux Docker Versions

Tags: sql-server, linux, docker, sql-server-2017, sql-server-on-linux

I currently have `Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (CTP2.1) - 14.0.600.250 (X64)   May 10 2017 12:21:23    Copyright (C) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Linux (Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS)`.

Are there any earlier versions available? SQL Server 2012, 2014, 2016?

I don't want to run into the problem where I need to back up and restore a database on an earlier version and it giving me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no linux versions  other than SQL2017.SQL2017 is the only version from  which Microsoft started supporting linux..

> Are there any earlier versions available? SQL Server 2012, 2014, 2016?

You can get SQL2014,SQL2016 developer editions ,but not sql2012.You can login into Visual studio dev essentials for 2016.For 2014,see below link

https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?PId=1682